# Creating scrollview with 20 labels with programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift

I am pretty new in Programming Swift so I am trying to achieve a scrollable task includes 20 labels inside. I made it  with storyboard but programmatically I failed..

Thanks in advance, a green view background and 20 labels orange. Can anyone show me how ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome new user.  Please DO NOT post physically enormous descriptive images.  As a Mac user (like me), you must surely know that you have to fix the silly "144 dpi" default before posting, and then, make it a reasonable size.

Answer (score 0):

So i am not very fond of advertising, but raywenderlich has an awesome tutorial on how to do this. It is quite easy, but it comes down to a scrollable view and a tableview with navigation links.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/5662524-your-second-ios-and-swiftui-app

Again, i am not advertising, just sharing some videos that really helped me understand Swift!

And for answering your question:

Use

Scrollview { put here your to-do code
} end of body

There is your scrollable view with all the labels!

Comment: If you look at the link: it is exactly the to-do app that the post-maker has asked :-) no part is talking about ads, just saying i don’t want to advertise, however it is exactly what he aks for

Answer (score 0):

Below code will print your label 20 times with scrollview.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var a = 0
    var COnstant: CGFloat = 20
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        while a<20 {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.backgroundColor = .orange
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.textColor = .black
            label.text = "I'm label \(a)"
            label.textAlignment = .center
            
            scrollView.addSubview(label)
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: COnstant).isActive = true
            
            COnstant += 40
            a = a+1
            
            if a >= 20 {  // if bottomanchor is not set then our scroll view doesnot work
                label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```